How to read a file from url with Node.js and Electron
How can I read a file with nodejs, even json, from url?
My file is on a server. I tried with ftp download but it is very inefficient.
Now is working on this, but is very slow for download and running...
I need for this type to get data and put in table.
let project_db;
fs.readFile('public/db/db.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    project_db = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(project_db.projects.length);
    for(let i = 0; i < project_db.projects.length; i++) {
        $('#projectTable tbody').append(`
            <tr class="rowT">
                <th scope="row" class="scope border-bottom-0">${project_db.projects[i].name}</th>
                <td class="border-bottom-0">${project_db.projects[i].date}</td>
                <td class="border-bottom-0">${(project_db.projects[i].project_constructii == true) ? "DA" : "NU"}</td>
                <td class="border-bottom-0">${(project_db.projects[i].project_hvac == true) ? "DA" : "NU"}</td>
                <td class="border-bottom-0">${(project_db.projects[i].project_instalatii_sanitare == true) ? "DA" : "NU"}</td>
                <td class="border-bottom-0">${(project_db.projects[i].project_instalatii_electrice == true) ? "DA" : "NU"}</td>
                <td class="border-bottom-0">${(project_db.projects[i].project_instalatii_incendiu == true) ? "DA" : "NU"}</td>
                <td class="border-bottom-0"><a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Vezi oferte</a></td>
            </tr>
        `);
    }
});


Your code looks somehow as if you try to mix client side (browser) and server side (nodejs) code.

you can't access file system like that in browser. Make a http get request using fetch api and let your server respond to this request with that json file. If its very large file use compression or spit the data into smaller pieces or embed that json data as javascript object in client side code.

i am using electron app, it's a browser app inside electron

You should have an error in the console(s) telling you what's wrong.
